# How to have a stable select component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chakra-ui

I have this code and when i click on other field, the select component returns to the title ...
Also, i have to click 2 or 3 times to see the value selected ...
Do you know why ?

```js
import { EnumDifficulty } from "@/components/Utils/EnumDifficulty";

const [difficulty, setDifficulty] = useState();
// ...

return (

<FormControl isRequired>
  <FormLabel>Niveau</FormLabel>
  <Select placeholder='Sélectionner le niveau' onChange={(e) => setDifficulty(e.target.value)}>
    {EnumDifficulty.map(diff => (
      <option key={uuidv4()}>{diff}</option>
    ))}
  </Select>
</FormControl>

);

/* EnumDifficulty.js */
const EnumDifficulty = [
    'Easy',
    'Medium',
    'Hard'
]

export { EnumDifficulty }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer : don't forget value={difficulty} in the select tag ...